# What type of tool do I need for this screw with a pin in the slot?

Tags: screws

[image]
What type of tool do I need for this screw holding my license  plate?

Answer (score 2):

This is *secure hex bit* or similar. There are a bunch of varieties. The basic idea is to take a "normal" head (e.g., a standard hex or Torx) and add something to prevent the regular bits from working. It is of limited use as far as real security because the bits are usually not hard to find. For example, [this set from Harbor Freight](https://www.harborfreight.com/33-pc-security-bit-set-68459.html) or [this set from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Klein-Tools-Magnetic-Screwdriver-with-32-Piece-Bit-Set-32510/100648026). Search for "security bit" or "tamper proof bit" or similar.

Comment: The tamper sets are handy and not very expensive, if short on funds see isherwoods answer.+

Answer (score 2):

If license plate theft isn't a concern where you are, simply break out that pin. Use a needle-nose plier, small flat screwdriver, or something similar and bend it back and forth a couple times. It'll fatigue and fall off, and you can use a standard allen key.

Comment: I break them all the time even though I have a tamper proof bit set, some times just quicker than finding the right tool.+

Comment: You can also use a small nail set. Put the nail set sideways against the nub and tap with a hammer.

Answer (score 0):

You need a TX Torx bit or screwdriver
Ordinary torx bits are numbered T10, T20 T30 Etc.
However you need the TX as in TX10 Tx20 Tx30 You can usually buy them all as one set.

Comment: That looks more like a hex than a Torx to me. However, there are plenty of bit sets that include both types.